# Prevent Vim from reformatting my line when I go to a new one

Tags: vim

I like the smart auto-indenting that VIM does when I start a new line, but I *hate* what it reformats the line I left.  I'm looking for a way to turn this off.

Simple example.  Say I have this HTML:

```
<!-- some multiline
     comment -->
<div id="foo" style="bar" class="baz">
```

If I put the cursor before the style tag and hit ENTER it reformats to:

```
<!-- some multiline
     comment -->
     <div id="foo"
       style="bar" class="baz">
```

Which is absolutely not what I want.

This frustrates me every single time I work on HTML files, as I'll start the line exactly where I want it and Vim will move it when I hit ENTER to go to the next line.

I still want it to auto-indent the new line (not always right on the first newline but that's easy to fix, and the rest all line up properly), but I never want it to change the line I was leaving.

Comment: Vim's behavior depends largely on what you have put in your `~/.vimrc`. Please, add it to your question. Also, what is the output of `:verbose set fo` when you are editing an HTML file?

Comment: formatoptions=tcq
        Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin.vim

Comment: My vimrc is rather complicated as I'm pulling in a number of other files (place I work provides a lot of stuff to automatically match style and such, though it doesn't seem to be doing so for html files).  It's not really feasible to post everything it's triggering.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it in my config, even messing with various settings like `g:html_indent_inctags` and `'indentkeys'` (see `:help html-indent` and `:help 'indentkeys'` and `:help indentkeys-format`). I think you're going to need to try removing bits of your config a little at a time until you find the culprit. I get no re-indentation of the previous line when I insert a newline in insert mode before the style attribute.